# styling/ adding transition to a slide show

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I'm trying to make a random slide show using react hooks and set interval. How can I make a transition/ animation between the images?

thank you!

```
    const imgArray = [img1, img2,img3,img4]
    const [slideImg, setSlideImg] = useState(imgArray[utilService.getRandIntInclusive(0, imgArray.length - 1)])
   
    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            setSlideImg(imgArray[utilService.getRandIntInclusive(0, imgArray.length - 1)])
        }, 3000)

        return function cleanup() {
            clearInterval(intervalId)
        }
    })

    return (
        <section className='filter flex'>
            <img src={slideImg} alt="" ></img>
          
        </section >)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add transition styles to the section.

Example

```
.flex {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.flex img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.flex img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: In that case, the transition would apply only when the image is hovered and I wand the animation to happen whenever the image changes

Comment: @lee - in the setInterval how about you programatically add the style for hover as classname and set it.

Basically if you are able to get the desired animation effect on hover, you just have to add the same class name in your react code dynamically if it makes sense. just like how your changing image source